# MPMoviePlayerViewController orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using cocos2d and i want to play a movie. For these purposes i've created `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and put it as a subview to `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]`. The problem is that it appears in a vertical orientation.

In the application orientation is set to landscape:

```
[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

How can i change the orientation of my player ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the cocos2d manual page about autorotation:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:autorotation

Basically you have to decide between two solutions:

1. Cocos2D handles orientation changes and you need to rotate the MPMoviePlayerViewController's view manually (e.g. using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation).
2. Cocos2D's opengl-view doesn't handle orientation changes and is inside a UIViewController that overrides `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and thus automatically rotates the view for you.

Comment: Cheers. Just realized that this questions goes way back ;-)